# Combining two matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can I make a two one-column matrices into a one two-column matrix, for example:

```
A = [1;2;3;4]
B = [6;7;8;9]
```

to become

```
C =[1 6; 2 7; 3 8; 4 9]
```

Comment: This is known as concatenation, in this case it is called horizontal concatenation. In MATLAB you have three options namely `[A, B]`, `cat(2,A,B)` and `horzcat(A,B)`. In your case `[A,B]` is the most natural. `cat` is very useful if you want to concatenate on higher dimensions. I'm not really sure what `horzcat` is for since `cat` exists anyway.

Comment: @Dan "MATLAB® calls C = horzcat(A1, A2,...) for the syntax C = [A1 A2 ...] when any of the inputs are an object." [(horzcat)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html)

Comment: @beaker but is there any reason for users to use `horzcat` over `cat` or `[,]`?

Comment: @Dan I think not, it's just the implementation of the concatenation over objects. It's possible that it could be used to overloading the concatenation operator for custom classes as, for example, with [`plus`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plus.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following syntax:

```
C = [A,B];
```

result:

```
C =

 1     6
 2     7
 3     8
 4     9
```